# How to display numbers of row in table to section in configuration system

Tags: database, system-config, table

I want to count the rows of table and display it to field in section system, can someone help me how to resolve this. Thanks!

Comment: it's really hard to tell but if you can include codes you have tried it will be easier for us to help you

Comment: can you pls tell me the idea to solve it